# How to cancel a new row on a Kendo Grid when the row editor closes?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that is in row edit mode. Whenever a user clicks the new record button, a new row is created in edit mode.  However if the user then clicks on the sorting, filtering, or paging components the new row will switch to read-only mode but remain within the grid.  The users find this last behavior kind of annoying, if a new row has no data and the editor is auto-closed then it would be better if the new empty row was removed.

Is there a way to do this without wiring up event handlers to each paging, filtering, or sorting input?

Comment: You can add validation to row inputs, so user need to focus them first before user sorts or filters grid data.

Answer (score 1):

You can pop confirm for user in case of sort or filter attempts.

```
requestStart: function(e) {
    if (e.type == "read" && this.hasChanges()) {
        if (confirm("You need to fill information before...") == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
},
```

Another way is add validation to grid editors via datasource schema configuration. Take a look at [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation)